# Multiple d3 charts in the same row

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The code below draws 1 pie chart and a legend on the left side of the screen. Right now, I am trying to draw another pie chart with legend right next to the one on the left (same row). I've tried using multiple divs in the html to make this work, but I want a more pure d3 solution in which the duplication happens in the d3 code rather than in the html or css.

```
        var w = 200;
        var h = 200;
        var r = h / 2;
        var color = d3.scale.category20c();

        var vis = d3.select(divId).append("svg:svg").data([descArray]).attr("width",w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");

        var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function (d, i) {
            return countArray[i];
        });

     // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

        // select paths, use arc generator to draw
        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class",                     "slice");

        arcs.append("svg:path")
             .on("click", function(d) {//clicking on individual arcs 
                arcs.selectAll("path").style("opacity", 1);//resets all arcs' opacity to 1
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.5);//sets clicked arc's opacity down
                alert(d.data + " " + d.value);
            })

            .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
            .transition().delay(function(d, i) { return i * 100; }).duration(1000)
              .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                   var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle+0.7, d.endAngle);
                   return function(t) {
                       d.endAngle = i(t);
                     return arc(d);
                   }
              })
            .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                return color(i);
            });


        var legend = d3.select(divId).append("svg")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("width", r * 4)
          .attr("height", r * 4)
        .selectAll("g")
          .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(230," + i * 27 + ")"; });



      legend.append("rect")
          .on("click", function(d) {
                alert(d.data + " " + d.value);
          })
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or can't you just use d3 to append a `div` and then append an `svg` to each `div`?

Comment: I believe that was what I was doing before but does that require having a separate div in the html for every pie chart that I was going to draw?

Comment: You can use d3 to append the `div`, it doesn't have to be in the HTML to begin with.  `d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "chart1");` will append a single div, just call it however many times you want.  You could also have your data in an array of arrays and bind the data to each div, though if you're just starting out, that's getting a bit more complex.

Comment: It would be better if you control the layout via div+CSS. You can make 2 div in the same row, and like @BenLyall suggest, you can select each div and append the svg content you need.

Comment: I need to make my d3 responsive, is that possible if i put it all inside of divs?

Answer (score 1):

put them in seperate divs but in the same SVG element

Presuming vis is your svgElement:

```
var firstChart = vis.append(div). // then put your first chart here
var secondChart = vis.append(div). // then put your second chart here
```

Comment: I have the problem where the secondChart is drawing on top on the firstChart. How do I manipulate their positions in d3?

Comment: d3.select(firstChart).attr("x", changeThis).attr("y", changeThis) < same for y value

Comment: make sure youre selecting the div. alot of the time the code is correct its just the selection is wrong. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/